# "Could we have" for guessing

Tags: modal-verbs

If we ask someone to guess how we escaped from the police, could we say:

> "**How could we have** escaped from the police?"

Also, say I want to used these words in a sentence instead of a question. Does this sentence seem correct?

> "I don't know **how you could have** succeeded the last year, but I'm sure you will fail this year."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could we have escaped from the police?

This is a valid sentence and I would envisage it used in a few situations

1. You were caught by the police, and someone asks you why you didn't escape from the them. You don't think that would have been possible so you now ask them how you should have gone about it.
2. Someone thinks you escaped from the police (either evaded or escaped from custody)

   - If you did escape, you are challenging them to come up with proof that you did (by presenting a method you could have used)
   - If you didn't escape, you are asking how that would have been possible

> I don't know how you could have succeeded the last year, but I'm sure you will fail this year.

This sentence implies that it is known that the person *did* succeed last year, so there is no need for the speculative *could have*. Just drop the *could have* and the *the*:

> I don't know how you succeeded last year, but I'm sure you will fail this year

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The "Could have" question is idiomatic. It tends to ask about morals or ethics.
"How could we have escaped from the police" asks "Why did we do this morally bad thing". Compare

> How could you have cheated on your girlfriend!?

It is normally a rhetorical question. I don't expect you to answer it. I'm just expressing surprise or shock at your bad behaviour.

You would ask "how did we escape from the police", or if really need it "How were we able to have escaped from the police".

On the other hand, if you are asking for someone to guess, then

> Guess how we escaped from the police.

The second sentence is rather odd, there is no real need for a "could have" question. It is also a horrid thing to say to somebody.

> I don't know how you succeeded last year, but I'm sure you will fail this year.

Comment: But he is asking his friend to guess how they escaped from the cops. Shouldn't it be "How do you think we escaped from the cops?" or "Guess how we outran the cops?"